# netfilter: drop packets having IP options

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, netfilter

I'd like to add a rule dropping an `IPv4` packet with any `IP option` following the header. I understand that `IHL` (Internet Header Length) field in he header contains the number of 32-bit words in the IPv4 header, including options. So, my understanding is that a rule should obtain the packet+options length from `IHL` field and compare to 20 (IPv4 header length without options), and if it is greater than 20, drop the packet.

Is there a specific `iptables` module that allows to inspect `IP` header and evaluate (do arithmetic operation) ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887072/6843158) help ? Alternatively [tc](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) (traffic control) should provide more flexibility - it even has an IHL option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` includes the `u32` match method which allows to do some bitwise (but not arbitrary arithmetic) operations, range comparisons and some pointer-like indirections on packet payload to match conditions:

> [`u32`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#u32)
>
> U32 tests whether quantities of up to 4 bytes extracted from a packet
> have specified values. The specification of what to extract is general
> enough to find data at given offsets from tcp headers or payloads.

It has its own sub-language grammar and the grammar and examples in the manual should be examined.

[IHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#IHL) is the IP header size (in 32 bits chunks rather than in bytes) and is part of the first 32 bits in the header (4 bits for version with value 0x04 for IPv4 followed by the 4 bits for IHL) and  , so if there's no option, this size should be the minimal size: 20 (bytes) / 4 (bytes per 32 bits words) so IHL = 5 (32 bits words). I won't handle invalid cases where IHL < 5, the IPv4 stack should already have taken care of this.

This translates into:

- take first 32 bits value
- mask it for IHL part
- shift it 24 bits
- compare equality to 5 (invert result with `!` on the match)

So to drop such incoming packet with *iptables*:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 '0 & 0x0F000000 >> 24 = 5' -j DROP
```

without inversion (matching 6 or greater instead):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 --u32 '0 & 0x0F000000 >> 24 = 6:0xF' -j DROP
```

The manual has a similar example where it's shifted by 24 bits then multiplied by 4 (so shifted only by 22 bits) to have bytes and not 32 bits words (because the `u32` pointers used later use 8 bits addresses), to retrieve the start of the layer 4 payload and continue for further operations:

> ```
> ... 0 >> 22 & 0x3C @ 0 >> 24 = 0"
> ```
>
> The first 0 means read bytes 0-3, >>22 means shift that 22 bits to the
> right. Shifting 24 bits would give the first byte, so only 22 bits is
> four times that plus a few more bits. &3C then eliminates the two
> extra bits on the right and the first four bits of the first byte. For
> instance, if IHL=5, then the IP header is 20 (4 x 5) bytes long.
> [...]

giving for OP's case:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 '0 >> 22 & 0x3C = 20' -j DROP
```

without inversion (and without caring about the fact that first next possible value isn't 21 but 24 nor about the exact maximum value as long as the value given is greater):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 --u32 '0 >> 22 & 0x3C = 21:0xFF' -j DROP
```

First method could be simplified into:

- take first 32 bits value
- mask it for IHL part
- compare equality to (5<<24) ie compare to 0x05000000 (ditto)

giving:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 '0 & 0x0F000000 = 0x05000000' -j DROP
```

or:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 --u32 '0 & 0x0F000000 = 0x06000000:0x0F000000' -j DROP
```

or even:

- take first 32 bits value
- compare value with range between 0x45000000 and 0x45FFFFFF for OK (IPv4 *always* starts with 4 and any value after the IHL part is to be ignored) or between 0x46000000 and 0x4FFFFFFF for not OK.

giving:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 '0 = 0x45000000:0x45FFFFFF' -j DROP
```

or:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m u32 --u32 '0 = 0x46000000:0x4FFFFFFF' -j DROP
```

Pick your choice.

Comment: thanks for a comprehensive answer. This helped greatly.